# Is there a way to call the DB connection globally, so that we dont have to call it every time

Tags: r, shiny

Currently I have called the DB connection at the beginning of every graph to fetch the data set and closed the connection once the dataset is loaded.

Is there a way to call the DB connection globally, so that we dont have to call it every time. I presume that this would improve the speed and at the same time the code would be easy to maintain.

sample code :

```
    output$moveyear1 <- renderPlot({
    #DB connection
    con = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='', password='', db='', host='')
    # query to fetch data.
    query = paste("select * from table1 ",sep="")
    result = dbGetQuery(con, query)
    dbDisconnect(con)
    # draw the graph
    ggplot(result, aes(gameYear,DEPARTMENT_NAME)) + 
      geom_tile(color="white", size=0.1,aes(fill=MoveCount))+
      facet_wrap(~TEAM_ID) + labs(x="GameYear") + ggtitle("Total Move made in a Year")
  }})

  output$avgtt <- renderPlot({
    #DB connection
    con = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='', password='', db='', host='')
    # query to fetch data.
    query = paste("select * from table2",sep="")
    result = dbGetQuery(con, query)
    dbDisconnect(con)
    # draw the graph
    ggplot(result, aes(gameYear,DEPARTMENT_NAME)) + 
      geom_tile(color="white", size=0.1,aes(fill=AvgTT))+
      facet_wrap(~TEAM_ID) + labs(x="GameYear") + ggtitle("Average Time taken for Move")
  }})
```

Comment: You could have it in the global.R file, which sits in the same folder as ui.R and server.R. global.R is loaded once when the application is initiated (when running `runApp`), so the connection will be available for you to use in `renderPlot`s.

Comment: Hi Lyzander thanks for the comment. Could you pls. provide me the sample app with the global.R file since I am new to R programing.

Answer (score 1):

Either put it in a file called global.R, or just put it outside of the server and ui functions:

```
library(DBI) ##or whichever one you're using
#DB connection
con = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='', password='', db='', host='')
# query to fetch data.
query = paste("select * from table1 ",sep="")
result1 = dbGetQuery(con, query)
dbDisconnect(con)
   #leave the connection open if they're from the same place
#DB connection
con = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='', password='', db='', host='')
# query to fetch data.
query = paste("select * from table2",sep="")
result2 = dbGetQuery(con, query)
dbDisconnect(con)

ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Your App"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
sidebarLayout(),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
     plotOutput("moveyear1"),
     plotOutput("avgtt")
    )
   )
  )

server <-  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$moveyear1 <- renderPlot({
ggplot(result1, aes(gameYear,DEPARTMENT_NAME)) + 
      geom_tile(color="white", size=0.1,aes(fill=MoveCount))+
      facet_wrap(~TEAM_ID) + labs(x="GameYear") + ggtitle("Total Move made in a Year")
  })

output$avgtt <- renderPlot({
ggplot(result2, aes(gameYear,DEPARTMENT_NAME)) + 
      geom_tile(color="white", size=0.1,aes(fill=AvgTT))+
      facet_wrap(~TEAM_ID) + labs(x="GameYear") + ggtitle("Average Time taken for Move")
  })

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```